# Imbalanced Dataset Classification using Keras

Tags: python, keras, imbalanced-data

I studied from [this](https://keras.io/examples/structured_data/imbalanced_classification/) site to learn Cost-sensitive learning.

I did model.predict and make a confusion_matric to see the result. Then I think the result shows this machine doesn't work at all.

Could you please check it? I added 3 things from that code,

1. Divided Test data

   ```py
   from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

   X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, targets, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

   num_val_samples = int(len(features) * 0.2)
   train_features = X_train[:-num_val_samples]
   train_targets = y_train[:-num_val_samples]
   val_features = X_train[-num_val_samples:]
   val_targets = y_train[-num_val_samples:]
   ```
2. prediction

   ```
   y_pred = model.predict_classes(X_test, batch_size=500)
   ```
3. Confusion Matrix

   ```
   from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, plot_confusion_matrix
   import numpy as np
   import pandas as pd

   con_mat = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred )

   classes=[0,1]
   con_mat_norm = np.around(con_mat.astype('float') / con_mat.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis], decimals=2)

   con_mat_df = pd.DataFrame(con_mat_norm,index = classes, columns = classes)

   import seaborn as sns
   plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (5,5)

   print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred ))

   sns.heatmap(con_mat_df, annot=True,cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
   plt.tight_layout()
   plt.ylabel('True label')
   plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
   plt.show()
   ```

   Then the result looks like it.

   [image: Confusion Matrix]

Please check where is wrong or comment about that code.

Thanks in advance!